# Meaning of long English sentences

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I’m struggling to decompose the meaning of long, long sentences that usually found in articles, newspapers etc. While going through a sentence, I merely remember what was at beginning of the sentence. Please help me. Besides reading more and more English articles what else should I do to improve my ability?

Comment: What advice would you give someone trying to learn your own native language?  It's the same for English.  Read more, and more difficult texts.  Learn vocabulary, and more important, how those words are used in actual sentences.  Practice practice practice.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Sentences in English literature have been getting shorter over the last few centuries.   Dickens' sentences were longer than Tolkien's sentences, which were longer than Tom Clancy's sentences.

Comment: @Jasper which is one reason why Tolkien is  a better writer than Clancy, IMO. Pratchett's sentences average longer than Clancy's, and Gene Wolfe's longer than Pratchett's

Comment: Try to identify the subject of the sentence, the verb of the sentence and the predicate or object of the sentence. The boys// walked// up the hill.

Answer (score 1):

It can help to break up long sentences into smaller ones starting with commas. Many sentences can afford to be made into several for the sake of clarity. If you post a problem sentence we will want to see your first attempt at pulling it apart into smaller ones.

You can also look at words that modify what follows. Long sentences can be made of large ideas started off with modifiers. You can circle such ideas and reduce them to one word temporarily to bring down the size of the task.

Instead of "In addition to Fred's *terrible* predilection to overeating and sloth, he has no housekeeping skills". It would be "In addition to Fred's *terrible* X, he has no housekeeping skills"

I use such tricks to improve my writing and penetrate others.